# How to Show C++ Results in Excel

Tags: c++, excel

I am trying to create C++ code that allows User Input in selecting a variety of fields, then it will calculate many different angles and show the users the results, as well as a graph.

However, it has been suggested to us by our lecturer that it may be a good idea to write the code to these calculations etc in C++, then input the results into Excel.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Literally looking for a way for the user to fill in the required values on C++ and then to be AUTOMATICALLY taken to the excel file to show the results in the table and graph format.

If this is not possible, is there a way to display the results in the table and graph format through C++?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: 1. This looks like homework. 2, Excel supports opening of CSV files, if you were to save the data like that and then open the app separately this would be trivial.

Comment: I never said it was/wasn't homework. It actually a small part of a complicated assignment where we are creating program for a robot hand to draw Syastro Letters, and we have to display the angles of the parts of the robot hand at all the different stages of its drawing. Was just looking for a way to draw these results on Excel, while coding in C++ thats all.

Comment: imo Excel automation (via COM or C++/CLI) is overkill for this purpose - just do the math in C++, output the results as Excel-readable text, and postprocess the file in Excel to do the display.  Your lecturer's instructions may preclude this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel provides COM interface which you can use from your C++ application.

This can be done in the way described in this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686

This link might also be useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10886/How-to-use-Managed-C-to-Automate-Excel

I think the second link would be better for you as its more of a step by step guide which should help you to workout the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, will have a look and study the links. Thanks again.

Comment: @Craig - like I said, I think the second one is better for you. It should help you work out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use COM Automation to automate excel.

The best way to do this is to use the vole library by Matthew Wilson at

http://vole.sourceforge.net/

Take a look at the examples. I do not think there is an example for excel, but there is one for microsoft word at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/VOLE_word.aspx

I have used vole in the past, and it makes it a whole lot easier